# Primus-Orderus Primes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

## Who are they?

Primus-Orderus Primes (POP) are primes which contain their **order** in the sequence of primes.
So the `nth` prime, in order to be POP, must contain all the digits of `n` in a certain way which I'll explain.

## Examples

Let's get things clearer:
All digits of `n` must appear among the digits of POP in the same order they appear in `n`

The `6469th` prime is `64679` which is POP because it contains all digits of `6469` in the right order .
`1407647` is POP because it is the `107647th` prime number

**14968819** is **POP** (968819th prime).So this challenge is **NOT** [OEIS (A114924)](https://oeis.org/A114924)

1327 is **NOT POP** because it is the `217th` prime (digits are not in the right order)

## The Challenge

You guessed right!
Given an integer `n`, output the `nth` POP

## Test Cases

input-> output

```
1->17
3->14723    
5->57089
10->64553 
29->284833  
34->14968819
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

**All these should be 1-Indexed**

Comment: 0-indexed, 1-indexed or dealer's choice?

Comment: @Shaggy I think this is 1-indexed such that it is compatible with the test cases (The order kind of matters).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It is the 1st POP, 7th prime

Comment: @MrXcoder: yeah, sorry, I probably phrased that poorly; what I was meaning to ask is 0-indexing allowed? Obviously, from the test cases, 1-indexing *is* allowed. Do we have a consensus, by the way, on which indexing we can use in a challenge if all we have to go by is the test cases and there's no explicit mention in the challenge specs?

Comment: @Shaggy 1-indexed. edited

Comment: Thanks, Bill. While, for the most part, your recent challenges have been very good, each of them has had a minor issue or 2 that has had to be cleared up in the comments, which is why I'd suggest you start Sandboxing your challenges, to allow us to catch those issues.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/41024) is the sandbox, for reference.

Comment: @LuisMendo I can hardly see that `f(3) = 14723`. Let alone `f(4)`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder it shouldn't really affect the test cases working if you zero or one index it. If you 1-index it, you check if the nth prime "contains" n. If you 0-index, you check if the n+1th prime "contains" n+1. The results are the same just shifted. That's why I think challenges like this should always be allowed to be zero or one indexed.

Comment: @geokavel The `0`th POP prime would be `101` in that case.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder There's no 0th Pop, because when you zero-index you check the n+1th prime.

Comment: @geokavel Oh yeah, I was thinking of 0-indexing the sequence, not the test cases.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 104 bytes

Extremely **efficient**

```
(t=i=1;While[t<#+1,If[!FreeQ[Subsets[(r=IntegerDigits)@Prime@i,{Length@r@i}],r@i],t++];i++];Prime[i-1])&
```

finds n=34 in under a minute

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
!fS¤o€Ṗdṗİp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9odXNr//8hZlPCpG/igqzhuZZk4bmXxLBw////NQ)

Not that fast, computes f(5) in around 30 seconds on TIO

#### Explanation

```
!fS¤o€Ṗdṗİp
 f       İp    Filter the list of prime numbers and keep only those for which:
  S¤o€Ṗdṗ       The "d"igits of its index in the "ṗ"rime numbers are an "€"lement of the 
                  "Ṗ"owerset of its "d"igits
!              Return the element at the desired index of this filtered list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), <strike>188</strike> 162 bytes

Quite efficient, finds n=34 in 22 seconds on [TIO!](https://tio.run/##JYxBDoMgFAX3nOLHlVSbWNsV5nfpJYwpGrESCxICqXJ5Stvdy7zJmMMtm65jnO2m4KnMUYNUZrPuRCYxQ5sP5UgZAYkrVgTei3wJGDvJ@kFPMHQr69laYBo9YuJ9Iwu8ELDCeauzKrv/HLKj1Ma7nBKPIQn/0M4CarG7h7FSiTzQZj9jm3PPSx44bfy3lT7tIMR4vX0A)

Could probably be golfed a bit

```python
from gmpy2 import*
def F(a,b):
 i=k=0
 while b[i:]and a[k:]:k+=a[k]==b[i];i+=1
 return"0">a[k:]
x=input()
u=z=1
while x:z=next_prime(z);x-=F(`u`,`z`);u+=1
print z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBDoMgFAX3nOKnK6g2sSbdYH6XXsKYohErsSAhkCKXp7bdvcybjN39spk659ltGp7a7jUobTfnz2SSM7R0KEfGCShcsSLwXtRLwtgp3g9mgqFbec/XAo/RIx68b1SBVwJO@uDMqTrdfw6JqIwNnjISMB3CPxR5QiOjf1intKSJNfGCLRVBlCIJ1oRv6/iMh5Tz7QM)

Comment: @Dopapp, wouldn't that add bytes?
 `__import__("gmpy2").`
is longer than
`from gmpy2 import*\n`

Comment: Oh right I don’t know why that came out different the first time. I probably forgot the quotation marks or something

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
µN<Ø©æNå½}®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v8wNWFiMWX//8K1TjzDmMKpw6ZOw6XCvX3Crv//MQ)

Extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ÆNDŒPḌċµ#ṪÆN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm5/L0UkBD3f0HOk@tFX54c5VQJH///8bAQA)

Extremely inefficient but works.